# Error: Failed to reach implicit threshold of 2 sub-policies, required 1 remaining

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I create new ORG for network hyperledger fabric. When I run (cli peer0.org1)

```
peer channel update -f org3_update_in_envelope.pb -c mychannel -o orderer0.orderer.io:7050
```

I get error message:

> got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- error authorizing update: error validating DeltaSet: policy for [Group]  /Channel/Application not satisfied: Failed to reach implicit threshold of 2 sub-policies, required 1 remaining

Anybody can help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BAD_REQUEST -- error authorizing update: error validating DeltaSet: policy for [Group] /Channel/Application not satisfied: Failed to reach implicit threshold of 2 sub-policies, required 1 remaining

which means

Channel update by default fabric has turned on majority of Admins

So you have to get the majority of admin signatures in order to update the channel

Majority: Suppose 4 organizations you need 3 organization admin signatures

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are working with wrong MSP directory and MSP ID. By default in order to be able to update channel configuration, e.g. to send config update transaction you need to be admin of orderer organization, therefore you need to correctly setup your `CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH` to point to `Admin` user and not regular one and MSP ID should be of orderer org, for instance:

```
export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/users/Admin@example.com/msp
export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
```

of course you also need to point `CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH` based on you configtx.yaml configuration file. Meaning it should point to corresponded MSPDir.